# jQuery Toggle with multiple unique DIVs?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am using jQuery toggle with a link and a div.  I will eventually have approx. 50 divs i want to toggle, and instead of creating a new function for each one, is there a way i can create a class and have it read unique ID's for each div? (if that makes sense)

For instance, i will have A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3..e.tc..

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#slickbox').hide();


  $('a#slick-toggleA1').click(function() {
    $('#A1').toggle(300);
    return false;
  });



});
```

Comment: you should write down your html markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<a class="clicker" href="#box1">Box 1</a>

<div class="coolbox" id="box1">I'm hidden!</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('.coolbox').hide();

$('.clicker').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href')).toggle(300);
});
```

Comment: I think he wants to click a link that then toggles a <div>

Comment: @Pickle, yea I edited it. I didn't see that in my haste at first.

Comment: Downvoting everyone else's valid answer to promote yours is not acceptable behavior, I'd advise you rethink that.  Upvoted all other answers to correct this.

Comment: @NickCraver sorry for the nearly 5 years late reply. I down-voted both of those answers because they used `return false;`, instead of using `event.preventDefault();`, the latter of which also has the effect of running `event.stopPropagation();`, which is most likely not necessary, and will break event handlers that are expecting an event for every click on the page (e.g., tracking scripts, etc.). Don't just assume that everyone is a troll.

Comment: @orokusaki look at the original question - you're making *assumptions* (outside the question) about what is or isn't needed. For instance, maybe he is doing this explicitly so it doesn't bubble. You also make the change without so much as an explanation of *why* you made the change.

Comment: @NickCraver let me see if I understand: **Only** addressing the exact question, without adding extra functionality, **is making assumptions**.

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate through wrapped sets with `.each()`:

```
$('div').each(function(i){
  $(this).toggle(300);

});
```

of course you can limit a wrapped set through a selector.
Alternativly, cou can use `.filter()` on all divs to find those divs you want to toggle.

Answer (score 2):

So lets add the class `slick-toggle` to your `a` tags. and lets change their id'`to something more definitively parseable -`slick-toggle-$ID` where $ID is the id of the div to toggle. then we do this in $.ready...

```
$('a.slick-toggle').click(function(){
   var divId = '#'+$(this).attr('id').split('-').pop();
   $(divId).toggle();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use different selector for div's being toggeled.
For instance class or custom attribute

```
$('.clicker').click(function(){
  $('[toggeled]').toggle(300);
  return false;
}
```

having in mind the following markup

```
<div class="clicker">Click Me</div>
<div id="first" toggled="true">First to hide</div>
<div id="second" toggled="true">second to hide</div>
<div id="third" toggled="true">third to hide</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your links a class and used the `href` like this:

```
<a class="opener" href="#A1">Open A1</a>
<div id="A1">Content here</div>
```

With this jQuery:

```
$('a.opener').click(function() {
  $(this.href).toggle(300);
  return false;
});
```

If javascript was disabled, the anchors would still navigate to the divs on the page as well.

Comment: Not sure why youre getting down votes for this. This is a good solution in that it will degrade. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Give the link a class, and stick the id of the div you want to toggle in the "rel" attribute - that's even standards compliant.

Then your function can look like this:

```
$('a.specialClass').click(function(){
  $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).toggle(300);
  return false;
}
```